# Clojure-coding standards-for invoking functions with many arguments

Tags: clojure

I am currenly using a function

```
(def mymap {})

(defn function1 [var1 var2 var3 var4 var5]
  ;calls another functions with all variables.
  (function2 var1 var2 var3 var4 var5)
)
```

But as this is having more parameters I would like to convert this to a map before calling functions2.

```
(function2((assoc mymap (keyword var1) var1
               (keyword var2) var2
               (keyword var3) var3
               (keyword var4) var4
               (keyword var5) var5 ))
  )
```

Is this the correct way? Do we have better way to do this(In java we direclty use some objects in this scenario)

Comment: This will be primarily opinion based, but similarly to Java, if the individual pieces of data are highly related, it can be appropriate to group them together. Grouping arbitrary data together just to reduce the arity of a function though isn't a good idea. And I wouldn't use `keyword` here like that. That would likely lead to an anti-pattern, since you'd need to know what the data is to get the key to get it out of the map. You'd want to give the map definitely named fields like it was an object in Java. I don't think we'll be able to give you a better answer without a concrete example.

Comment: By your usage here though, it almost looks like those variables should be put in a sequence like a vector instead of structure with "named" keys like a map.

Comment: you would advise to use defrecord or just map without keyword.

Comment: in my case assume that it is non-related variables and the number of variables might increase tomorrow.

Comment: Depends on the scenario. Records are used mostly for Java interop. And I wouldn't create a map like `{var1 var1, var2 var2}` if that's what you're suggesting. I'd use a Set (`#{var1, var2}`) if you just want to track membership, or a vector (`[var1, var2]`) if you just need to list multiple things. Again though, I don't think we'll be able to help you without seeing a more concrete example.

Comment: If they aren't related, then that suggests that your function is potentially doing too much and needs to be broken up into smaller functions that each handle a smaller part of the problem.

Comment: I feel you might be interested in watching Jason Wolfe's presentation about [prismatic graph computing](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Graph-Clojure-Prismatic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For general function args, I always go in order from the biggest to the smallest,
 in either size or "importance" (somewhat subjective).

---

***However, if you have more than 3 args***, I prefer to pass a map containing the args and appropriate keyword names.

The [Tupelo Clojure library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) has some tools to make this easy.  The macro `vals->map` takes multiple variable names and constructs a map from the (keywordized) variable name to its value, like:

```
  (let [ctx (let [a 1
                  b 2
                  c 3
                  d 4
                  e 5]
              (t/vals->map a b c d e))]
    (is= ctx {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5})
```

The macro `with-map-vals` does the opposite, deconstructing map values into local variables named for their keys. It is similar to the Clojure `:keys` destructuring, but in (IMHO) a more natural form:

```
    (let [{:keys [a b c d e]} ctx]    ; Clojure destructing syntax
      (is= [a b c d e] [1 2 3 4 5]))

    (t/with-map-vals ctx [a b c d e]
      (is= [a b c d e] [1 2 3 4 5])
      (is= 15 (+ a b c d e)))

    (t/with-map-vals ctx [b a d c e]  ; order doesn't matter
      (is= [a b c d e] [1 2 3 4 5])
      (is= 15 (+ a b c d e)))

    (t/with-map-vals ctx [b a d]      ; can ignore stuff you don't care about
      (is= [d a b] [4 1 2]))

    (throws?
      (t/with-map-vals ctx [a b z]    ; throws if key doesn't exist
        (println "won't ever get here")))))
```

---

***If you have nested data in maps and/or vectors***, you can use the more powerful `destruct` and `restruct` tools.  Here is a brief example ([from the unit tests](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/cljc/tst/tupelo/core.cljc#L1977)):

```
  (let [info  {:a 1
               :b {:c 3
                   :d 4}}
        mania {:x 6
               :y {:w 333
                   :z 666}}]

    (t/it-> (t/destruct [info {:a ?
                               :b {:c ?
                                   :d ?}}
                         mania {:y {:z ?}}] ; can ignore unwanted keys like :x
              (let [a (+ 100 a)
                    c (+ 100 c)
                    d z
                    z 777]
                (restruct-all)))
      (t/with-map-vals it [info mania]
        (is= info {:a 101, :b {:c 103, :d 666}})
        (is= mania {:x 6, :y {:w 333, :z 777}})))
```

As you can see, a question mark `?` will cause the corresponding value to be destructed into a variable named for the corresponding keyword.  It is also possible to create explicit variable names like so:

```
(dotest
  (let [info  {:a 777
               :b [2 3 4]}
        mania [{:a 11} {:b 22} {:c [7 8 9]}]]
    (let [z ::dummy]
      (t/it-> (t/destruct [info {:a z
                                 :b [d e f]}
                           mania [{:a ?} BBB {:c clutter}]]
                (let [clutter (mapv inc clutter)
                      BBB     {:BBB 33}
                      z       77
                      d       (+ 7 d)]
                  (restruct-all)))
        (t/with-map-vals it [info mania]
          (is= info {:a 77, :b [9 3 4]})
          (is= mania [{:a 11} {:BBB 33} {:c [8 9 10]}]))))))
```

It also works for mixed maps & vectors:

```
  (let [data {:a [{:b 2}
                  {:c 3}
                  [7 8 9]]} ]
    (t/destruct [data {:a [{:b p}
                           {:c q}
                           [r s t]]} ]
      (is= [2 3 7 8 9] [p q r s t])))
```

Comment: fixed it to be more precise